# How to show html style text in excel cell with SpreadsheetGear

Tags: html, excel, styles, spreadsheetgear

I get a string that contains html content, like this:
"

## i am head

hello

"

now, i want to write this string into excel cell, and let these html tags render the **bold** style.

How can i do this with spreadsheetgear?

Answer (score 1):

SpreadsheetGear does not support parsing and rendering HTML.  If you put this type of content in a cell, the raw markup will be displayed instead.

SpreadsheetGear does support adding rich-text (RTF) to a cell, but you would need to do this with SpreadsheetGear API using:

- IRange.[GetCharacters](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~GetCharacters.html)(...)
- [ICharacters](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.ICharacters_members.html) interface

The following example code would render something similar to this:

[image: Rendered rich-text formatting from sample code]

```
// Create new workbook.
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet;
IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;

// Add text to A1 which we'll format below...
cells["A1"].Value = "This Is My Header\n\nHello World!";

// Format "header" as bold and with a larger font size.
ICharacters charsHeader = cells["A1"].GetCharacters(0, 17);
charsHeader.Font.Bold = true;
charsHeader.Font.Size = 18;

// Format "Hello" text.
ICharacters charsHello = cells["A1"].GetCharacters(19, 5);
charsHello.Font.Italic = true;
charsHello.Font.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.DarkRed;

// Format "World" text.
ICharacters charsWorld = cells["A1"].GetCharacters(25, 5);
charsWorld.Font.Underline = UnderlineStyle.Single;
charsWorld.Font.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.DarkBlue;

// Expand column width to accommodate header text
cells["A:A"].ColumnWidth = 30;

// Save and view in Excel...
workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\rtf.xlsx", FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);

// ...or attach to SpreadsheetGear's WPF WorkbookView to 
// confirm RTF is displaying as expected (NOTE: the WinForms
// WorkbookView does not support rendering RTF).
workbookView.ActiveWorkbook = workbook;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if the WinForms WorkbookView supported rendering RTF.